# Covering space of a graph is a graph

Tags: algebraic-topology, covering-spaces

I'm trying to understand the following proof in May's *Concise*.

[image: Proof of the Theorem]

Can someone enlighten me as to what this easy path lifting argument is?
I guess that if $e\in E\setminus E^0$, then I can lift the segment of the edge containing $p(e)$ to a path starting a $e$. Can I then uniquely extend this over a neighborhood, eventually arriving at a vertex?

Comment: I don't understand something, if you have $p:E\rightarrow B$, you don't have $p^{-1}(B^0)=E^0$ ?

Comment: @Tsemo I think that $E^0$ is mean to be defined as that, there is no given CW structure on $E$.

Comment: $E^0$ is not the set of vertices ?

Comment: @Tsemo I think it should just say $E^0:=p^{-1}(B^0)$.

Comment: The morphism of graph $p$ induces a morphism between the vertices $p_0:E^0\rightarrow B^0$, I believe that the domain of $p_0$ is $E^0$, so $p^{-1}(B^0)=E^0$.

Comment: @Tsemo $E$ is _any_ topological space.

Comment: I see, $E$  is not a graph

Answer (score 1):

I think the proof should work like this.

Take a point $e \in E\setminus E^0$ then $p(e)$ does not belong to $B^0$ hence there must be a path $\alpha$ that parametrizes an edge having in the interior $p(e)$.

Let assume that $\alpha(t)=p(e)$ for a $t \in (0,1)$, by a lifting argument one can prove that there is a unique lifting $\beta \colon [0,1] \to E$ such that

- $p \circ \beta = \alpha$
- $\beta(t) = e$.

Since $\alpha$ parametrizes an edge of $B$ we have that $\alpha(0), \alpha(1) \in B^0$, while $\alpha(s) \in B \setminus B^0$ for $s \in (0,1)$.

Since both $E^0$ and $E \setminus E^0$ are saturated sets, that is they are unions of fibers of $p$, we have that

- $\beta(0), \beta(1) \in p^{-1}(B^0)=E^0$
- $\beta(s) \in p^{-1}(B\setminus B^0)=E\setminus E^0$
  which implies that $\beta$ parametrizes an edge of $E$.

Hope this helps.

Comment: Let's see if I can do the lifting argument.

Comment: Let $\beta$ be the unique lift of $\alpha|_{[t,1]}$. We claim that the infimum of all $s\in[0,t]$ for which there exists a unique extension of $\beta$ to a lift of $\alpha|_{[s,1]}$ that maps $t$ to $p(e)$ is equal to $0$. Suppose that we have an extension $\gamma\colon[s,1]\to E$ with $s>0$. Let $U$ be a path-connected evenly covered neighborhood of $p(\gamma(s))$ in $B\setminus B^0$, i.e. an open interval. Then $p^{-1}(U)$ is a disjoint union of open intervals, of which a unique one contains $\gamma(s)$. This yields the desired unique extension to $[s-\epsilon,1]$ for some $\epsilon>0$.